# How to identify segments with child layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm working on a project which involves manually going through a city map and changing features of streets with planned construction in the future. The layers are:

- `scenario_network` is just a road map
- `scenario_change` is where the child layers (created in the `scenario_network` layer) are placed in an attribute table.

The problem is that the child layers don't have any spatial attribute (in the table at least) so I can't zoom to them or highlight them. But if I do choose a segment of the `scenario_network` layer then the child layer is visible, so it's obviously connected geospatially somehow.

I have been panning through the map looking for where changes need to be made via the creation of a child layer and now I'm stuck because I know I definitely have missed some segments.

My idea for finding these is to create a layer highlighting the `scenario_network` segments that have child layers (via the `scenario_change` layer).

How would I go about doing this? I tried virtual layers and SQL but that didn't lead anywhere (I have very limited experience with it though). Can anyone think of an easier way of doing this or how I would do it in a virtual layer?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your data structure from your description. Can you add a screenshot of your list of layers (IE the Layers panel)? It would also be helpful to see the Identify Feature window or the Attribute Table. Use the [edit] link to add information to your question.